# CoreFoundation and general pointers

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, pointers, core-foundation

Simple question. I seem to get the impression that `CoreFoundation` isn't really designed for handling, for example, pointers to structs (containing CF objects). `CFArrayAppendValue` will take any pointer value to append, but I get segfaults if I try and `CFShow` it.

I also note that there's no `CFTypeID` for a bare pointer, though you could possibly argue that you could detect bare pointers by exhaustion from other CF types, but that's a pain.

Is my impression correct? Should I be using CF types whenever possible and avoid mixing CF with non-CF things?

If I want to work with structs, should I instead use something like a `CFDictionary` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe CoreFoundation containers are intended to be used to store anything but CoreFoundation objects. Any bridging between regular C structs could potentially be done via CFData objects and wrapper methods (see also http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/22246-implementing-new-corefoundation-types.html ).